# Erro consulta mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Tenho uma consulta no NodeJS com MongoDB:

```
filter:['abertos','cancelados'];

schemas.chamados
    .find({STATUS_CHAMADO : {"$in" : filter}})
    .exec(function(err, dados) {
        if(err) return callback(err);
        else {
            return callback(dados);
        }
    });
```

Apresenta o seguinte erro:

```
Object {message: "Cast to string failed for value "undefined" at path "STATUS_CHAMADO"", name: "CastError", type: "string", path: "STATUS_CHAMADO"}
```

Alguem sabe o que pode ser ?

Quando o usuário selecionar o filtro no front-end com angular, o node buscaria estes valores.

Comment: Este filter vem de um uns checkbox passados pelo angular,
Se ele vier assim: ["aberto", null, null], acontece o erro, agora se ele vier ["aberto", "cancelado", "finalizado"]
vai normalmente.

Comment: Sim é constante, mesmo usando uma string não funciona !
So da erro se a variável filter vier do angular, se eu setar ela manualmente funciona.

Comment: Acontece o mesmo erro !!

Comment: mesmo se for `{'status_chamado' : { '$in': filter}}` aparece `"Cast to string failed for value "status_chamado" at path "status_chamado""` pq daí não precisaria fazer o cast, se já for string

Comment: Sim, mesmo assim aparece o erro, mais somente quando o filter é variável. Se eu definir var filter=['aberto','cancelado','finalizado'] não da erro.

Comment: (Removi os comentários anteriores) Talvez esse filter não esteja chegando como array, tente validar colocando algo como `console.log(typeof filter)`

Comment: Testei, retorna como object array

Comment: Já tentei de tudo ao meu conhecimento, alguem tem alguma ideia de que pode estar acontecendo ?

Comment: Então é isso.  Deveria ser um array. Converta para array que vai resolver

Comment: Caputo, resolvido. Você estava certo !
Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Como @Caputo, disse, somente converti `object` em `array` conforme abaixo:

```
var arr = Object.keys(filter).map(function(k) { return filter[k] });
```